# Ошибка подключения к PHPmyadmin в XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу подключиться к базе данных.
Когда пытаюсь зайти в phpMyAdmin, получаю такую ошибку:
[image: ошибка phpmyadmin]

Адресная строка: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Почему нет доступа, не могу понять, в настройках все указано верно (я ничего там и не менял), единственное, что было изменено - это порт подключения. Был 3306, поставил 3310, так как 3306 был занят другой программой.
Как это можно исправить?